# JQuery .on() method not firing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use the JQuery `on()`  method. Basically I am trying to write an alert box similar to the one on here. If you've ever tried to vote on your own comment or thread, you'll know what I'm talking about.

I have a JS function like below which simply returns my box with the message.

```
function alert_box(msg){
    return "<div class='alert-box'><p>" + msg + "<br /><i>( Click to Close )</i></p></div>";
}
```

I then call the alert-box like so

```
$(that).append( alert_box(data.err) );
```

The above works as expected but the problem is this function not triggering. The `.alert-box` gets added with the above code but doesn't get removed with the below.

```
$('.alert-box').on({
    click: function() {
        $('.alert-box').remove();
    }
});
```

I assume its something to do with the `.alert-box` class being added after the DOM. Anyone got any pointers on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The form of `.on()` you were using does not handle dynamically added content.  If you want to change it to handle dynamic content, then you can use this where you pass it a common parent object and then an argument for the selector to filter by:

The prototype for that form of `.on()` is this: `.on( events-map [, selector] [, data] )`.  And your code would work like this:

```
$(document.body).on({
    click: function() {
        $('.alert-box').remove();
    }
}, '.alert-box');
```

In this new form, you're attaching an event handler to a parent object and then looking for clicks in any children that match the '.alert-box' selector.  It's best to pick a parent object that is as close to where your clicks will be, but one that doesn't change.  I used document.body here just because I know that exists and you haven't shown your other HTML for me to know what else could be used.

Comment: Thanks for this jfriend. `document.body` is fine and is what i'll have to use because the `.alert-box` could be added to anything. Are there any speed issues if I do use `document.body`?

Comment: The only issue is that you don't want to add a ton of event handlers to the same top level object (like document.body) or the event handling could bog down having to check every click against a lot of selectors.